# Non-breaking characters in C# (WPF)

Tags: c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have a text with some special characters ('|', '+', '/', '-'); these characters produce a breakline in a WPF textbox control. How to replace these for non-breaking equivalents?

WRONG:

```
 sdfsdasdf+ 
 asdfasdfsadfsdjhfjsdfj/
 kjsdkfhksdfsd|
 kdhfvkh
```

CORRECTLY:

```
 sdfsdasdf+asdfasdfsadfsd
 jhfjsdfj/kjsdkfhksdfsd|k
 dhfvkh
```

Thanks

Comment: These characters don't produce line breaks, could you post some code for XAML and code behind

Comment: `<TextBox Height="132" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,134,0,0" Name="Mensaje" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" TextWrapping="Wrap" >
        wkfjwkjflqkjwhflqkjhwfokqjw|lkjlkjnlkjnlkdjvnlkjdvnlksjndv+dfkvdslkvlskdmfvmvlkd-dskjvnslkdjvbkasjnvlksjnclksjndc/kjefnkjsdnvksjdnfvksknclskjdncs 
        
</TextBox>`

[The image here](http://tonhiohouse.hostei.com/sq1.png)